# Flask + Celery how to capture the ForkPoolWorker value?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, celery

By any chance, How to capture the ForkPoolWorker value (e.g ForkPoolWorker-8) in a Celery worker application?

Celery Logs:

```
[2023-08-31 11:53:53,151: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] init a new token
[2023-08-31 11:53:53,819: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] Update mt1234, set status = 1
[2023-08-31 11:53:53,851: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] Sending MT ...
```

Here is my example code

```
@shared_task(ignore_result=False)
def push_sms(json) -> int:
    #May I capture the "ForkPoolWorker-8" here?
    return 1
```

Many thanks in advance.

I have tried with celery.signals but the method does not seem to be executed

```
from celery.signals import celeryd_after_setup
@celeryd_after_setup.connect
def capture_worker_name(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print("Try to get worker name")
    print('{0}'.format(sender))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer by myself

```
from billiard import current_process
...
p = current_process()
print(f"process name is {p.name}")
>> process name is ForkPoolWorker-8
```